# Hyperledger Fabric Manually generate the artifacts

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have clone the `fabric-samples` and tried to run the `balance-transfer` sample. When run it as it is, it runs smoothly with no issues. But when I remove the `crypto-config` folder and generate it with command `cryptogen generate --config=./cryptogen.yaml`. Then when I try Login Request with any user other than Jim I get error, adding image of logs.
[image]
Can anyone guide what am i doing wrong here?

System Configuration

```
**OS**
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 
**Docker**
Client:
 Version:      17.09.0-ce
 API version:  1.32
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   afdb6d4
 Built:        Tue Sep 26 22:41:23 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
Server:
 Version:      17.09.0-ce
 API version:  1.32 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   afdb6d4
 Built:        Tue Sep 26 22:42:49 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
**GoLang**
go version go1.9.2 linux/amd64
**Docker Images**

dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycc-v0-f021beca29998638e0bb7caa7af8fda7f1e709518214a3181d259abcb2347093   latest              d69f39aae76e        About an hour ago   145MB
dev-peer1.org1.example.com-mycc-v0-f76f22af4a360dd2172e04459b1687f933a29d4b8d6c97ea0a4a21144a108361   latest              7cbe869e1a5e        About an hour ago   145MB
hyperledger/fabric-ca                                                                                 latest              17f38f1c8e80        3 weeks ago         238MB
hyperledger/fabric-ca                                                                                 x86_64-1.0.3        17f38f1c8e80        3 weeks ago         238MB
hyperledger/fabric-tools                                                                              latest              ac1f4a1e58a6        3 weeks ago         1.33GB
hyperledger/fabric-tools                                                                              x86_64-1.0.3        ac1f4a1e58a6        3 weeks ago         1.33GB
hyperledger/fabric-couchdb                                                                            latest              b2188fa55138        3 weeks ago         1.47GB
hyperledger/fabric-couchdb                                                                            x86_64-1.0.3        b2188fa55138        3 weeks ago         1.47GB
hyperledger/fabric-kafka                                                                              latest              9e2a425c9dd6        3 weeks ago         1.29GB
hyperledger/fabric-kafka                                                                              x86_64-1.0.3        9e2a425c9dd6        3 weeks ago         1.29GB
hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper                                                                          latest              3b50cfad9af3        3 weeks ago         1.3GB
hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper                                                                          x86_64-1.0.3        3b50cfad9af3        3 weeks ago         1.3GB
hyperledger/fabric-orderer                                                                            latest              fd1055ee597a        3 weeks ago         151MB
hyperledger/fabric-orderer                                                                            x86_64-1.0.3        fd1055ee597a        3 weeks ago         151MB
hyperledger/fabric-peer                                                                               latest              b7f253e87c0c        3 weeks ago         154MB
hyperledger/fabric-peer                                                                               x86_64-1.0.3        b7f253e87c0c        3 weeks ago         154MB
hyperledger/fabric-javaenv                                                                            latest              1d778fcc14c0        3 weeks ago         1.41GB
hyperledger/fabric-javaenv                                                                            x86_64-1.0.3        1d778fcc14c0        3 weeks ago         1.41GB
hyperledger/fabric-ccenv                                                                              latest              2e5898d8b21b        3 weeks ago         1.28GB
hyperledger/fabric-ccenv                                                                              x86_64-1.0.3        2e5898d8b21b        3 weeks ago         1.28GB
hello-world                                                                                           latest              05a3bd381fc2        6 weeks ago         1.84kB
hyperledger/fabric-ca                                                                                 x86_64-1.0.2        7e53be14f804        8 weeks ago         238MB
hyperledger/fabric-tools                                                                              x86_64-1.0.2        ba9750b2565d        8 weeks ago         1.33GB
hyperledger/fabric-couchdb                                                                            x86_64-1.0.2        3f922f54bd68        8 weeks ago         1.47GB
hyperledger/fabric-kafka                                                                              x86_64-1.0.2        0b4b1d249e65        8 weeks ago         1.29GB
hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper                                                                          x86_64-1.0.2        1efb063147d3        8 weeks ago         1.3GB
hyperledger/fabric-orderer                                                                            x86_64-1.0.2        6efd17e86e65        8 weeks ago         151MB
hyperledger/fabric-peer                                                                               x86_64-1.0.2        0e2ed51971c9        8 weeks ago         154MB
hyperledger/fabric-javaenv                                                                            x86_64-1.0.2        0be45dbd7ff4        8 weeks ago         1.41GB
hyperledger/fabric-ccenv                                                                              x86_64-1.0.2        d0f166e1a89e        8 weeks ago         1.28GB
hyperledger/fabric-baseos                                                                             x86_64-0.3.2        bbcbb9da2d83        2 months ago        129MB
hyperledger/fabric-membersrvc                                                                         latest              b3654d32e4f9        12 months ago       1.42GB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After generating certificate using `cryptogen` tool you need to update the `docker-compose.yaml` according to the new keys generated by the `cryptogen` tool. For example in case of `balance-transfer` example, you will need to update keys
[here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release/balance-transfer/artifacts/docker-compose.yaml#L15); the key can found at `..artifacts\channel\crypto-config\peerOrganizations\org1.example.com\ca`
[here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release/balance-transfer/artifacts/docker-compose.yaml#L18) the key can found at `..artifacts\channel\crypto-config\peerOrganizations\org1.example.com\ca`
[here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release/balance-transfer/artifacts/docker-compose.yaml#L31) the key can found at`..artifacts\channel\crypto-config\peerOrganizations\org2.example.com\ca`
and [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release/balance-transfer/artifacts/docker-compose.yaml#L34) the key can found at `..artifacts\channel\crypto-config\peerOrganizations\org2.example.com\ca`

Answer (score 0):

If you to create and utilize crypto-config by generating it using cryptogen tool make sure that to you clean everything from previous configuration firstly e.g. channel artificates, channel transactions etc.

Comment: No luck, I removed the images created by the running the example before, Deleted the previous artifacts and genereted new channel.tx, genesis.block and crypto-config files. Cleared the dockers Data folder

Comment: Try to pass the absolute path in your configuration instead of default path.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand very well when you get the error. When you execute the `cryptogen` tool, you generate the certificates for the users of the `balance-transfer`. Is the user Jim among those users? Which is the configuration that you have in the cryptogen.yaml file?

**Edit**

I understand that you get the error because you are trying to enroll again the user Jim.

If you use the cryptogen tool, you dont' need to use the CA. You have to define a via to create the certificates.

However, if you don't use the cryptogen tool and you registry and enroll your user via de Fabric CA, you should have a DB for your users. The DB is created in the Fabric CA Server. Could you query the DB of the CA?! Probably, it would be a sqlite file.

Comment: Hi, I can easily enroll Jim, but the Node JS Sdk can (should?) enroll users other than Jim.  Basically I am trying to enroll JimA not Jim. Also if I execute `cryptogen` on the `cryptogen.yaml`, i am unable to create channel with user Jim also. I get BAD_REQUEST. Can I access the CA DB file? If so, how?

Comment: Thank you for the update, I didn't know about the CA DB. can you please guide me to some link regarding that?